# Center multiple independent items in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

As you can see, two's a label , two images and two labels, all independent. I need to center all of these items,

[image: This the image I want it to look]

[image: Here is my output]

i am doing this job programmatically. please suggest

try with way but failed :

```
 func setupViews(){


    view.addSubview(orderLocation)

    orderLocation.addSubview(ownOrderTagImage)
    orderLocation.addSubview(ownOrderTagLabel)
    orderLocation.addSubview(ownOrderLocationImage)
    orderLocation.addSubview(ownOrderLocationLabel)

    //Change the width and height accordingly
    view.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: orderLocation)
    view.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|-50-[v0(20)]|", views: orderLocation)


    orderLocation.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0(18)][v1(70)]-20-[v2(18)][v3(80)]|", views: ownOrderTagImage, ownOrderTagLabel,ownOrderLocationImage,ownOrderLocationLabel)


    orderLocation.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0(20)]", views: ownOrderTagImage)

    orderLocation.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0(20)]", views: ownOrderTagLabel)

    orderLocation.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:[v0(20)]|", views: ownOrderLocationImage)

    orderLocation.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:[v0(20)]|", views: ownOrderLocationLabel)

}
```

Comment: What do you mean with failed? Can you show a screenshot how your result looks like with the code you posted?

Comment: Also, show an image of how you *want* it to look.

Comment: @DonMag i added an image could you check that please . how can i achieve . please help me

Comment: @Nef10 i added output screenshot what is the result

Comment: Is the first screenshot the desired look? Or do you want one label on top of the other? @cristainlika3

Comment: @Stefan i want to achieve but second one my code output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a group of four views that you want to lay out in a row, and you want to center the group as a whole within a superview.

There is no anchor at the center of the group for you to use in a constraint. All of the anchors available are at the centers or edges of the individual subviews.

You cannot constrain “distance from leftmost item to superview” to be equal to “distance from rightmost item to superview”, because that constraint would involve four anchors, and an auto layout constraint can only involve two anchors.

One solution is to add a helper view that tightly surrounds the group of views. Then you can constrain the helper view's center anchor to the superview's center anchor.

The simplest way to do it is to put the group of views in a stack view, and center the stack view. If you use a stack view, you'll also need a “spacer” view to separate your “tag” views from your “location” views.

Here's my test result:

[image: test result]

Here's my test playground:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let rootView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 100))
rootView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9568627477, green: 0.6588235497, blue: 0.5450980663, alpha: 1)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = rootView

let tagImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Toggle"))
tagImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
let tagLabel = UILabel()
tagLabel.text = "#YUIO9N"
let locationImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Gear"))
locationImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
let locationLabel = UILabel()
locationLabel.text = "Garmany"

let spacer = UIView()

let rowView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [tagImageView, tagLabel, spacer, locationImageView, locationLabel])
rowView.axis = .horizontal
rowView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

rootView.addSubview(rowView)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    tagImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 18),
    spacer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
    locationImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 18),
    rowView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
    rowView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rootView.centerXAnchor),
    rowView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rootView.topAnchor, constant: 20)])
```

Comment: thank you so much .. would you help me to  resolve the issue :  
swift compiler error UIStackView it is only available for ios 9

Comment: if i set deployment target 9 it is working fine but deployment target 7 not working . suggestion please

Comment: Look for a `UIStackView` back-port using your favorite search engine, or use a plain `UIView` and set up the constraints manually.

Comment: i seem UISackView available from ios 9 . but product target os 7 . what can i do please help me

Answer (score 0):

`addConstraintsWithFormat` is not inherently a part of swift, it's a an extension on the Visual Format Language.

I believe you are using the following code as your extension.

```
extension UIView {
func addConstraintsWithFormat(_ format: String, views : UIView...) {


    var viewsDictionary = [String: UIView]()

    for(index, view) in views.enumerated(){
        let key = "v\(index)"
        viewsDictionary[key] = view
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    }
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))

}
```

You must remember to include information like that in future questions.

Anyways, you are missing the view you are adding the views to.
In your case you should have an ImageView as your superview

First create the ImageView object which in your case is going to be that bar

```
let imageView: UIImageView = {
    let imgV = UIImageView()
    //put the name of the image you are using in the quotes
    imgV.image = UIImage(named: "")
    imgV.layer.masksToBounds = true
    imgV.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    return imgV
}()
```

Make sure the photo you use is properly formatted and add barView as the super view of your sub views and their constraints.

**Try**

```
//here you add the view
view.addSubview(imageView)

imageView.addSubview(ownOrderTagImage)
imageView.addSubview(ownOrderTagLabel)
imageView.addSubview(ownOrderLocationImage)
imageView.addSubview(ownOrderLocationLabel)

//Change the width and height accordingly
view.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0(100)]|", views: imageView)
view.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0(10)]|", views: imageView)


imageView.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0][v1]|", views: ownOrderTagImage, ownOrderTagLabel)

imageView.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0][v1]|", views: ownOrderLocationImage, ownOrderLocationLabel)

imageView.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0(44)]", views: ownOrderTagImage)

imageView.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0(44)]", views: ownOrderTagLabel)

imageView.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:[v0(30)]|", views: ownOrderLocationImage)

imageView.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:[v0(30)]|", views: ownOrderLocationLabel)
```

Comment: One final comment. I would highly recommend you look into using an autolayout method such as NSLayoutConstraints. The visual formats language can only go so far. If you are building more detailed, complicated layouts, then NSLayoutConstraints or NSAnchors are the way to go in my opinion.

Comment: not in out put my expected .. could you check my update answer